# Conseguir el url de un "botón" definido como <i> con un evento de click

Tags: html, jquery, typescript, input, scraping

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño script para facilitarme el navegar por una página. Sin embargo, me topé con un problema al querer conseguir un link. Mi conocimiento en webdevelop es bastante limitado, así como en typescript (pero necesito usarlo porque trabajo con una librería específicamente desarrollada con él).

El "botón" está definido así:

```
<div id="backButton" class="">
    <div class="backButtonIcon ng-star-inserted">
        <i class="lni lni-chevron-left fa-2x clickable text-shadow">
            ::before
        </i>
    </div>
    <!---->
```

El problema es que por más que rebusqué y resbusqué dentro del código de la página no pude obteren ninguna referencia a él.

Al interactuar con $(selector).click() responde debidamente y va a la página deseada... pero si le pido el evento onclick no obtengo nada. Mi pregunta es ¿existe alguna manera de accionar el evento onclick y captar la url a la que redirige? A ser posible anulando ese pedido, para evitar que salga de la página.

Comment: No todos los elementos tienen su link como atributo. El código puede escuchar un evento del elemento y reaccionar. Tal vez prefieras usar Selenium.

Comment: ¿Has intentado con document.querySelector(), document.querySelectorAll()? Un saludo